# Using PipedStream to upload file to SharePoint using Java Graph SDK causes Error "The Content-Range header is missing or malformed"

Tags: java, sharepoint, stream

As the title said, i'm trying to upload a vast generated in-memory file to SharePoint. To save memory, I try to use PipedStream to upload it but I have an exception with that cause:

```
com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error code: invalidRequest
Error message: The Content-Range header is missing or malformed.
```

My upload call is:

```
LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem> largeFileUploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask<>(uploadSession, msGraphServiceClient,
      inputStream, streamSize, DriveItem.class);

    try {
      LargeFileUploadResult<DriveItem> uploadResults = largeFileUploadTask.upload(CHUNK_SIZE, null, (current,
        max) -> log.debug(String.format("Uploaded %d bytes of %d total bytes", current, max)));

      return uploadResults.location;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("File upload failed.", e);
    }
```

Is it possible to upload a file as a stream or do I need to know the exact file size before?
That's because I don't know the value of the `streamSize` variable.

Comment: *a vast generated in-memory file* in what type is that contained?

Comment: It'a a CSV file

Comment: You're saying it's *in memory*. How?

Comment: I generated it directly into a PipedOutputStream using jasperreport template, so I don't save it into a temporary file on the disk.

Comment: To progress, we probably need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some research i think it is not feasible. The GraphService from Microsoft SDK accepts an InputStream, but digging into the code shows that he wants the exact file size to upload it. Probably the proper parameter should be FileInputStream or a ByteArrayInputStream.

Comment: *Probably the proper parameter should be FileInputStream or a ByteArrayInputStream.* Right. But if you want to do it in memory it will have to be the latter